# ADO.NET Entity Data Model handle parent-child relation in the same table

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, ado.net-entity-data-model

In my application I use ADO.NET Entity Data Model for data access. 
I have the table categories (id, parentId, name, displayName). I want to access the children of a category. Does ADO.NET Entity Data Model support this behavior ... or I have to query manually each time? I would prefer to have the children in a List property that is lazy loaded.

Thanks,

Radu D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it supports such relation. If you have the relation defined in your database this association should be created automatically when you update model from database. If you don't have this relation defined in database you can define it manually in the model as foreign key association. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444450/ado-net-ef-how-to-define-foreign-key-relation-in-model-first-approach/5445806#5445806) is some general example how to define a relation. You just need to do that on the same entity.