# EF4: Creating a 0..1 to Many Association

Tags: entity-framework-4, mapping, entity-relationship

I am trying to add an association that I didn't have originally. I realized that two tables were technically related, and that some navigation properties might simplify what I would have otherwise had to do manually. The tables and their keys look like this:

```
Import
Primary Key:
   Number : Int32
   Date : DateTime

Hour
Primary Key:
   DepartmentID : Int32
   UserNumber : Int32
   Date : DateTime
```

The association is named ImportHour. Import.Number maps to Hour.UserNumber, and Import.Date maps to Hour.Date. I am trying to add an association that is 0..1 on Import, and * on Hour with navigation properties and no additional foreign keys. When I do this, the designer tells me that the association is not mapped. If I then generate the DDL, it creates new fields Hours.Import_Date and Hours.Import_Number (Hours is the actual database table name for the Hour entity). If I manually map the fields, I end up with the following error:

```
Error 3021: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 332:
Each of the following columns in table Hours is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
Hours.Date is mapped to <ImportHour.Hour.Date, ImportHour.Import.Date>
Hours.UserNumber is mapped to <ImportHour.Hour.UserNumber, ImportHour.Import.Number>*
```

I am not really sure what is happening, and I don't think I understand the 'mapping' process well enough to figure this out. It almost seems as if it wants a quintuple key, instead of realizing that the one key maps to the other. I look at my other one-to-many associations, and they do not even have table mappings; I think they have referential constraints instead, but you obviously can't have a referential constraint with a 0..1 to many association.

Comment: How did you create your entity objects to begin with? Have you done any customizations to the entity objects? If not, and as a last effort, simply rebuild the objects (I assume you used the template in VS). Could be problematic if you generated POCO support and then split the POCO entities into a separate library from the ObjectContext.

Comment: I built the entity objects with the designer, and then used 'generate database from model' to generate a .sql file that I executed to create the database. I haven't added any customization.

Comment: I seem to have 'fixed' it by choosing a 1 to many association, with a referential constraint using my preexisting columns. Not sure what will happen if I try to load hours values that don't have a matching import values though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from other databases I have since used, the issue here seems to be that the EF model requires a foreign key to already exist in the database. While I cannot seem to get EF to generate one, it will accept one if it already exists. (Contrary to what I said in the question, you *can* have a referential constraint on a 0..1 to many (nullable) foreign key).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to define relation but in your case you must use the Foreign key association. It means that once you draw association in entity model you must [select it and define referential constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444450/ado-net-ef-how-to-define-foreign-key-relation-in-model-first-approach/5445806#5445806).

You cannot have 0..1 on `Import` because in such case `UserNumber` and `Date` in `Hour` must be nullable. That is what that relation mean. If no principal entity exists (`Import`) FK properties in dependent entity (`Hour`) will be null.

Btw. using `DateTime` in primary key is [not recommended](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/abouttn/flash/tips/tips_031604.mspx).

Comment: **You cannot have 0..1 on Import because in such case UserNumber and Date in Hour must be nullable.** ok... that's wierd. I guess what I was going for was like something that would enable a full outer join, since there may or may not be records in either table. **using DateTime in primary key is not recommended.** none of the reasons given in the link apply, and the DDL made my tables from .NET DateTime type anyway; there is no .NET Date type as far as I know. The records in this case should be unique to the day.

Comment: If you want to support scenarios like full outer joins you must have FKs nullable otherwise you cannot have related entities without parent entities.

Comment: it seems to work with a 1 to many association. the only thing I am unsure of is what will happen if I use the Hour.Import navigation property if there does not happen to be a record there (which is why I thought I should use 0..1). I guess that what I tried to accomplish is really technically unsupported by EF. With dynamic SQL I could setup such a situation where given an Hour record, I can find zero or one Import records, and given an Import record I can find Many (0..*) Hour records, and it doesn't require nullable keys or anything.

Comment: Once you have FK defined in the database you cannot have filled Number and Date of unexisting import. It is whole meaning of referential integrity.

Comment: I know, but in this scenario there is no FK constraint. It is not even really a 'foreign key', it's more that the records happen to match by date and user number, not that the hour table has a strict relation to the import table. It's a weaker kind of association where given a date and usernumber, I can find 0..1 Imports and 0..* Hours. (or given an Import I can find 0..* Hours, and given an Hour I can find 0..1 Imports).

Comment: But relations in EF are supposed to work in the same way so once you want 0..1 EF demands dependent FK to be nullable.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I'm not understanding. I have two entities Parent (Bill) and Child (InvoiceItem). InvoiceItems are created all the time, but begin orphaned. Later a Bill is created and it encompasses a collection InvoiceItems. I can use the UI to create such an association (0..1 Parent to * Child) and it creates a nullable FK on the Child and both entities' navigation properties, but on compile it says the multiplicity is invalid... that it cannot have a * many collection for a nullable FK. Whats did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

@Sahuagin this may be long after your question but did you try after adding the association, deleting the scalar property in the designer -- example after creating the ImportHour association, delete the hour.usernumber and hour.date from your hour entity.
this way the independent association established this way is the only relationship between yuor entities - thats the meaning of independent association

Comment: If I recall, deleting the scalar properties gave me the mapping error. It's possible that I was misunderstanding the meaning of a `0..1 to *` association; making it `1 to *` instead has worked as far as I know. The database has been in use since then, and I have not tinkered with it since.