# Entity Framework Compound Key (Many-To-Many Relationship with a Payload)

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-key, compound-key

I've got database tables like this:

[image: diagram of three database tables: Person, Membership, and Team]

A person may be a member of many teams. A team may have many members. Each person may have a position (think job title) within the team.

I've tried to set this up with ADO.NET Entity Framework and get errors:

> Error 3021: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line ... Each of
>   the following columns in table
>   Membership is mapped to multiple
>   conceptual side properties:
>   Membership.PersonId is mapped to
>   <MembershipPerson.Membership.PersonId,
>   MembershipPerson.Person.Id>

and

> error 3021: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line ... Each of
>   the following columns in table
>   Membership is mapped to multiple
>   conceptual side properties:
>   Membership.TeamID is mapped to
>   <MembershipTeam.Membership.TeamId,
>   MembershipTeam.Team.Id>

The primary key of my *Membership* entity is a compound key of two foreign keys. I think that's the problem.

What must I do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you use independent association on the property which is both part of primary key and foreign key. EFv4 introduced Foreign key associations ([the difference is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275)) and once you expose foreign key in the entity [you must define foreign key association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444450/ado-net-ef-how-to-define-foreign-key-relation-in-model-first-approach/5445806#5445806). After defining referential constraints delete mapping of independent association in Mapping details window.