# Entity type not created for table with composite key

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4

I'm using VS 2010, Entity Framework 4.3 and MySql.Data.Entity v6.3.5 to work with a MySQL DB with a couple dozen tables.  I use the ADO.NET DbContext Generator.

Everything works well enough other than two tables don't get Entities created for them.  Both have a similar structure in that they have a composite key composed of foreign keys to other tables.  So, one is a region_flavor table that maps the (ice cream) flavors assigned to a particular sales region.  It looks like so

```
region_flavor
-------------
RegionId INT(10) PK NN
Flavor VARCHAR(64) PK NN
```

`RegionId` is a FK to the regions table and `Flavor` is a FK to the ice_cream table.

There's another table with essentially the same situation.

When I do an "Update from Database", I see that there is, in the Model Browser, the table `region_flavor` listed under my **IceCreamModel.Store\Tables / Views** folder.  But under my **IceCreamModel\Entity Types** folder there's no Entity Type.

I don't receive any .edmx errors when I do the update from the DB.

Perhaps I'm missing something here.   Ideas?

I can post more info if that's helpful.

Comment: Perhaps this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862352/entity-framework-compound-key-many-to-many-relationship-with-a-payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal behavior. This is junction table used to model many-to-many relation in database. If it doesn't contain any additional column EF doesn't need to map it to entity because many-to-many relation is modeled directly and translated to table rows internally by EF.

Comment: OK, thanks. I understand why this is the case now.  Appreciate your clearing this up for me.

Comment: Interesting, checking this theory out now. Wasn't the case apparently in earlier versions of MySQL EF, in my expereince.