# How to get the Entity to Table mapping for many to many relations from the metamodel in Enity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, metadata

Is there any way we can get the underlying "many to many table" joining the two entities in entity framework.

For example if we have Product and Order entities, how can we get the underlying conjunction table Product_Order that joins the Product and Order table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need that? It will make interaction with objects much more complex. EF by default hides these pure junction tables by correct many-to-many relation.

Comment: @Ladislav: thanks for the quick reply. Actually, I have to do some business logic on the many to many table. And I am doing so by overriding the: public int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) method of ObjectContext.Is there any way we can get this tablename just as we get a table name for an entity using ToTraceString() method. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895455/

Comment: a pure junction table is not a business entity, rather just a way to express a `many-to-many` relationship in SQL (that's why EF hides it). Therefore, `doing business logic on this table` doesn't make sense. Perhaps you could describe your scenario in more detail, and there could be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @Yakimych - thanks. I want a list of IDs(List<long>) of Order entity in Product entity instead of list of Orders (List<Order>). And the requirement is not to have List<Order> in Product entity. So, when the Product entity is loaded the List<long> should also be filled. And when saving the Product entity, the List<long> which contains the corresponding Ids of Order should also be updated. Hope this clears the requirement that i want to do.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to expose junction table as an entity but it is not common / needed:

- You will start with this:

[image]

- Delete many-to-many relation between your `Product` and `Order` entities
- Create new `ProductOrder` entity in designer (either by using toolbox or context menu)
- Define two properties in your new entity corresponding to Foreign keys defined in your junction table - `ProductId`, `OrderId` - make sure that both are marked as entity key (they must be composite primary key in the database) and have the same type as PKs
- Open Mapping details and map your new entity to junction table

[image]

- Create two new one-to-many associations. The frist between `Product` and `ProductOrder` and the second between `Order` and `ProductOrder`.
- In Property window of each added relation set up referential constraints ([as described also here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444450/ado-net-ef-how-to-define-foreign-key-relation-in-model-first-approach/5445806#5445806).

[image]

There is very big chance that if you need this you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Great answer. As a sidenote: a quick but dirtier solution would be to add some "dummy" column to the junction table (e.g. `Id` as identity). It would get exposed by EF as an entity in that case.

Comment: @Ladislav, Not sure why you'd say, "There is very big chance that if you need this you are doing something wrong." since this is very common occurrence needed whenever you need to add a attribute to the relationship. You can create a many-to-many relationship between homes and people for example but you'd need to do this to add a purchase date or anything else that belongs to the relationship instead of either primary entity.

Comment: @spadelives: I agree with you but once you have additional property in the junction table it becomes a "new entity" and VS will generate it automatically - you will not need to do it manually. The comment was meant for this elementary case where you are working with pure junction table.

Comment: I wanted to do this so I could join to the many-many table in linq-sql.  Without this, isn't it necessary to have to go through navigation properties to filter on ProductId when selecting from Order.  Avoiding the Nav property filter and using a regular join generates cleaner and better SQL (no use of exists).