# no intellisense for many to many association

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to build a query in LINQ for EF5. My model has set up an Association with two foreign keys, shippingcompanycontacts with a contactid and a shippingcompanyid. There is no intellisense for that "table" (it shows up as a table in mySQL) I tried accessing the data this way to no avail. ( I hard coded the id)

```
 Dim testquery = (From s In ctx.shippingcompanies Where s.Id = 1 Join
                c In ctx.contacts On s.Id Equals c.Id Select New With {c.LastName}).ToList()
```

I really need to access the association table but there is no intellisense for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The association table is not available in EF by default. You have only `Contacts` and `ShippingCompanies` and each of them contains navigation property to their related counter part so your query can be defined as (C#):

```
var query = from s in ctx.shippingcompanies 
            where s.Id == 1
            from c in s.contacts // accessing navigation property
            select c.LastName;
```

You can [manually edit EDMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910517/how-to-get-the-entity-to-table-mapping-for-many-to-many-relations-from-the-metam) and bring `ShippingCompanyContacts` as a new entity but it is not usual way to use EF.

Comment: Can you explain why s.contacts works? Isn't s just the shippingcompanies table in variable form? It has no field contacts, so why does s.contacts work? (Which it does by the way)

Comment: That is the magic behind EF. It translates the navigation property back into relations in database and makes joins with junction table and contacts table.