# What is error 3004?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, database-schema

I updated my database and the I got this message:

```
 Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
 927:No mapping specified for properties User.Username in Set User.
 An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
 Entity is type [Db_AcsModel.User]

C:\Users\User\Desktop\MVC\ACS.Domain\AcsModel.edmx
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063701/error-3004-problem-in-mapping-fragment-starting-at-line

Answer (score 0):

You most likely added a new filed or deleted a filed but the property for the field still exist in your designer and entity class you can manually delete or map the entity variable or you can delete the entity and update your model again.

Comment: I just changed a property so i can delete tables with cascade reference.

Comment: you mean like from string to int

Comment: Nop, it was just two tables, one of them had a fk from the another one, then i wanted to delete with both of them so i changed it to cascade reference and then i got that message on Visual Studio