# Create navigation/association from table to view in EF 4.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, compiler-errors, sql-view

I have a Container table with ContainerId as PK (int), and a (readonly) view vwBlobRef with a BlobRefId column set as PK and ContainerId as FK.    By the way, I have to manually set the BlobRefId as the Entity Key for the view...

Now I want to create an association to get Navigation properties from the table to the view (the other way around is not as important). So I add the one-to-many association and deselect the checkbox "Add Foreign Key to the vwBlobRef"

Now I get:

> Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - ContainervwBlobRef.

I have no idea how to build this mapping. I can right click on the association line and select either the table or the view. But I don't understand which one to select and what to select in the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [referential constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444450/ado-net-ef-how-to-define-foreign-key-relation-in-model-first-approach/5445806#5445806). In your case you are trying to define association which doesn't use your FK and requires mapping. But because such relation doesn't exist in database you have nothing to map to.

Comment: Thanks that soved it! I had some complaints about the multiplicity against my view (due to nullable columns?) and had to change from exactly one to zero-or-one. -Victor