# EF Association, Extra Column

Tags: entity-framework, associations

I'm trying to set up my EF Model. I have 2 tables: Posts and Comments. I right clicked and added an association and I see a new column was generated "PostPostID". Is this necessary? Can I delete it? When I do, I get this error: There is no property with name 'PostsPostID' defined in type referred by Role 'Comments'.
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: I unchecked "Add foreign key properties..". That did it. Knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That column was added as Foreign Key to your association but you probably already have foreign key as part of the entity - `PostID`. You will need to [map `PostID` as FK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444450/ado-net-ef-how-to-define-foreign-key-relation-in-model-first-approach/5445806#5445806) for the new association.