# Have a FK relationship and a Navigation property at the same

Tags: entity-framework

I'm Using EF 4.1 Model First approach

Is it possible to have a foreign key relationship and a Navigation property at the same time for the same type.

For ex I have a `Job` entity and a field called `PaymentType_ID` with a foreign key relationship to a `PaymentType` entity. When I do an insert it works fine.

Then I add a Navigation property using the same association that is used for the FK, when I try insert I get the following error "Invalid column name `'PaymentType_PaymentTypeID'`."

It seems EF is for some reason adding another column by itself even though a FK already exists.

Is this possible or what am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but your property doesn't follow default naming convention so you must manually pair the FK with navigation property for example through data annotations:

```
[ForeignKey("PaymentType_ID")] // Name of FK property
public virtual PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
```

Comment: how would I achieve this using Model Fist approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444450/ado-net-ef-how-to-define-foreign-key-relation-in-model-first-approach/5445806#5445806

Comment: I accepted this answer as it was the only one provided. But it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible You should clear navigation property & relationship
see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564

Comment: Could you please extend your answer? This is a little thin